# Rails parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page in my Rails app which uses URL parameters to filter and sort the outputted list of contents.

When one of the links for filtering/sorting is clicked, it either adds or removes a URL parameter. The parameters are coming from Rails' `params` array. I have noticed that the URL's being set on the links are including things like `action=index` and `controller=garages%2Fcars`. How can I stop Rails from auto adding these extra parameters into the URL's? I would prefer only my custom filtering and sorting parameters to be shown.

**UPDATE:**
I've been trying to use `.slice` to solve this. My code is:

```
@valid_params = [:type, :letters, :misc, :sort, :country]
parameters.merge(options).slice(*@valid_params)
```

When I check `parameters`, I don't get any shown? Any thoughts on why this could be?

Comment: Change ``parameters`` per ``params``?

Answer (score 0):

Rails has a solution for this. At the bottom of the relevant controller you'll want something like this.

```
  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :username, :password)
  end
```

You would then refer to user_params[:email] to access that attribute elsewhere in the controller for example.